# How to set scss variable to css variable use javascript

Tags: css, dynamic, sass, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to set scss variable to css variable in a method in vue.

```
$color: #000;
--varColor: #{$color}
```

I want dynamic set by props, but its not working. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

```
'--backgroundColor': `#{${props.backgroundColor}}`,
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. *SCSS* is a *CSS* preprocessor, emphasis on pre here. So when your code is executed, the *SCSS* won't be there anymore, it will be compiled to *CSS* instead.

But you can manipulate *CSS* with *JavaScript* [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#values_in_javascript) like `style.setProperty`.

Comment: thanks Gh05d, because in this case just use scss variable ($color) for pass to child component. when setProperty css variable equal scss variable not working.